# Can I use Google Docs Editor for files not in my Google Docs Account

Tags: google-drive

I know it is possible to use the Google Docs Viewer with any publicly accessible worddoc or pdf file.  Is it possible to do the same with the google docs editor?  Is there a way I can give a URL to a .doc file and load it into google docs to be edited and added (if the user wishes) to my google docs account?  I appreciate I can't update the file at the URL, but really all I want is for the doc to be able to be edited slightly and then either printed or downloaded?

Is this possible, or do I have to go the full api route?

I will take any answer, but I am particuarily interested in php.

Comment: Google Docs Viewer was retired. See my [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99937/88163) to a related question for the reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this viewer you can `Edit` online or just save it in your Google Docs:

[image: Save/Edit google docs viewer]

I think they don't have a direct link that you could use to simply convert the files and have them in the edit mode directly. You might have to take the API route.