# Google Docs Viewer returning no content

Tags: google-docs, google-api

I have a basic page that previews documents in our repository with 
`http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=`

For instance

`http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/egov/digital-government/digital-government-strategy.pdf`

Should display the [White House PDF](https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/egov/digital-government/digital-government-strategy.pdf).  This has worked flawlessly for the last 6 years.  This last week it stopped displaying content.  I can't find any announcement or info on this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Docs Viewer Page, No Longer Available](http://googlesystem.blogspot.mx/2015/02/google-docs-viewer-page-no-longer.html), (unofficial source) the Google Docs Viewer web app is no longer available since the beginning of 2015. The referred source mentions that the "embedded" parameter was still available, but several comments from 2016 reports that embedded URL have issues.

Comment: the url is still available at `https://docs.google.com/gview?url=URL_TO_YOUR_FILE`  but somehow it shows **WOOPS There was a problem displaying this image.** when a csv file is provided, but works for other microsoft docs and PDF e.t.c